# Query to a list doesn't work

Tags: list, splistitem, query, spquery

I want to get the number of comments from the list "Comments" of a blog site. To do that, I have a query with this code:

```
 using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb(new Guid(WebId)))
                { 
                    SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["Comentarios"];

                    if (oList.ItemCount > 0)
                    {
                        var query = new SPQuery()
                        {
                            Query = "<Query><Where>" +
                                        "<Eq>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name='ows_PostID' LookupId='TRUE'/>" +
                                            "<Value Type='Lookup'>" + IDEntryBlog + "</Value>" +
                                        "</Eq>" +
                                    "</Where></Query>",
                           // ViewFields = "ID",
                            //ViewFieldsOnly = true,
                            IncludePermissions = false,
                            RowLimit = BlogInfo.MaxNumberOfComments
                        };
                        SPListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(query);
                        ncomments = items.Count;
                    }
                }
```

I always receive the total number of elements. Have a look to the xml content of items: http://pastebin.com/g2nGpLKj

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First off, you should spell `Query` with a capital `Q` in your query tag. But if this is server side code, as it looks like, you should omit the `<Query>`part from the query

Comment: Yep, your query is malformed which is why you aren't getting the results you'd expect

Comment: @Robert It doesn't mind, but changed. Thanks

EricAlexander, Do you mind tell me where?

Comment: Use this tool to build your CAML query. http://www.u2u.be/Software

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't mind", one of the two things I mention is very likely to stop your query from functioning correctly

Comment: @RobertLindgren When the query is wrong, it throws an exception. Anyway, I changed it as I said and the result is the same.

Comment: So you have removed the Query-tags and still get the same behaviour?

Comment: Which comments you wish to get by this CAML query? I mean what's the logic?

Comment: If I remove Query tags, I get an exception.

@AtishDipongkor Thank you very much for that program. That saves my life :D :D I did it! The only thing is that the software you send me, add an "@" before the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code generated by the tool that @Atish commented. Note the "at"

```
SPList list = web.Lists[new Guid("d4dd7678-6dd9-47de-9d0c-951368081bdf")];
var q = new SPQuery()
{
    Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='PostID' /><Value Type='Lookup'>3</Value></Eq></Where>"
};


var r = list.GetItems(q);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks like `Server Object Model`. Based on my experience on using CAML queries, I can suggest you to get rid of `<Query>` tags. So update your query as below

```
Query = "<Where>" +
                "<Eq>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='ows_PostID' LookupId='TRUE'/>" +
                    "<Value Type='Lookup'>" + IDEntryBlog + "</Value>" +
                "</Eq>" +
        "</Where>"
```

Comment: Exception. If you're interested how I resolved this little issue, check my answer. Thank your interest in my problem.

Comment: @Daniel976034 : I am glad that the problem is solved. :)